# Ubuntu & Wine - Running multiple programs but want terminal windows not to appear

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04, wine, gnome-terminal

I'm currently trying to get multiple versions of the same software to run without the terminal window showing. I'm using Ubuntu 18 and Wine. I have tried the below bash script; including && doesn't seem to prevent the terminal from running as well as the software I want. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "wine software1/terminal.exe" &&
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "wine software2/terminal.exe" &&
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "wine software3/terminal.exe" &&
```

etc etc... the gnome-terminal will first appear x amount of times (depending on how many of the software I open) then the actual software will run. This method does work, granted. But can get a bit messy when trying to find the actual programs I want amongst  the terminals.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `wine` without using `gnome-terminal`

```
#!/bin/bash
wine software1/terminal.exe &
wine software2/terminal.exe &
wine software3/terminal.exe &
```

Also, to run in the background you end with `&`. `&&` is for testing whether a previous command completed successfully before running the next command.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think that wine could run that way.

Had to make a small iteration which was to remove the second & as only software1 was running and didn't start the other software until the first was closed.

Thanks again :)

Comment: @user14149738: If this resolved your issue, you should mark this answer as accepted. Click on the checkmark button at left of this answer, right below the up-down arrow buttons.   See also: ["What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).